# How do I fix problem with getting "permission denied" when Flask server is saving an image file

Tags: python, apache, nginx, flask

We are having problem having Flask save image files on our server.  We’ve made sure that the directory we’re trying to write to has write permission.  We used chmod images 777.
But we are getting “Permission Denied”.

I did "chmod 777 images" directory
ls -l result is 
drwxrwxrwx 2 someuser someuser 4096 Jul 16  2021 images

Result of form with file submission:
Same response: Permission Denied

Here are the relevant fragments of code we have:

```
<form action="/someurl" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="workform">
<input  type="file" name="photobefore” />
<input  type="file" name="photoafter" />
<input type=“submit” />
</form>
```

SERVER:

```
@main_blueprint.route(‘/someurl’, methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def workperformed():
        message = “submitted”
        before = ""
        after = ""
        try:
            if len(request.files) > 0:
                for name in request.files:
                    file = request.files[name]
                    if name == 'photobefore':
                        before = file.filename
                    if name == 'photoafter':
                        after = file.filename
                    if not file.filename == '':
                        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
                            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
                            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))

        except Exception as e:
            message = "dir:" + os.getcwd() + " error:" + str(e)

        return message
```

Result:
dir:/ error:[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/someuser/public_html/mydefensiblespace.org/html/templates/static/images/20190721_184017_HDR.jpg'

Comment: Are all the parent directories of the images folder publicly readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web server (assuming Apache or Nginx on Ubuntu) needs to be the owner of the folder where you are saving images

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/folder
```

I believe Nginx also needs the folder to be executable

```
chmod +x /path/to/folder
```

Also since your path to folder is outside of `/var/www` you will need a directive in your virtual host

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName domain.com
 # ...
 <Directory /path/to/folder>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
 </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I get an 'invalid user' response

Comment: I tried user 'apache' .  That worked but still get "Permission Denied".  Though I wasn't able to apply executable permission with chmod +x.  Still get rw- state with ls -l only.

Comment: I have drws--s--x for images folder

Comment: What does `ls -lha /path/to/folder`  tell you about the owner/perms of the folder? You might need to run those commands with `sudo`

Comment: Actually, looks like your `/path/to/folder` is outside of `/var/www` you will likely need to add a directive to your virtual host config ...  edited my answer to include.

Comment: sudo ls -lha /home/someuser/public_html/mydefensiblespace.org/html/templates/static.

Comment: drws--s--x 2 apache   apache   4.0K Jul 16  2021 images

Comment: I looked for this virtual host configuration file you speak of..  I looked through the subfolders of /var/www.  I had no luck.  Do I need to create one?

Comment: Got saving working by switching to using the root path /var/www instead of /home/someuser